# Nested parsers in happy / infinite loop?

Tags: haskell, happy

I'm trying to write a parser for a simple markup language with happy. Currently, I'm having some issues with infinit loops and nested elements.

My markup language basicly consists of two elements, one for "normal" text and one for bold/emphasized text.

```
data Markup
    = MarkupText   String
    | MarkupEmph   [Markup]
```

For example, a text like `Foo *bar*` should get parsed as `[MarkupText "Foo ", MarkupEmph [MarkupText "bar"]]`.

<del>Lexing of that example works fine, but the parsing it results in an infinite loop</del> - and I can't see why. This is my current approach:

```
-- The main parser: Parsing a list of "Markup"
Markups     :: { [Markup] }
            : Markups Markup                    { $1 ++ [$2] }
            | Markup                            { [$1]       }

-- One single markup element
Markup      :: { Markup }
            : '*' Markups1 '*'                  { MarkupEmph $2 }
            | Markup1                           { $1            }

-- The nested list inside *..*
Markups1    :: { [Markup] }
            : Markups1 Markup1                  { $1 ++ [$2] }
            | Markup1                           { [$1]       }

-- Markup which is always available:
Markup1     :: { Markup }
            : String                            { MarkupText $1 }
```

What's wrong with that approach? How could the be resolved?

**Update:** Sorry. Lexing wasn't working as expected. The infinit loop was inside the lexer. Sorry. :)

**Update 2:** On request, I'm using this as lexer:

```
lexer :: String -> [Token]
lexer [] = []
lexer str@(c:cs)

    | c == '*'              = TokenSymbol "*"   : lexer cs
    -- ...more rules...
    | otherwise             = TokenString val   : lexer rest

  where (val, rest) = span isValidChar str
        isValidChar = (/= '*')
```

The infinit recursion occured because I had `lexer str` instead of `lexer cs` in that first rule for `'*'`. Didn't see it because my actual code was a bit more complex. :)

Comment: To ensure completeness on this question can you post the before and after of your lexer. That way others can see what went wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just a warning it has been a while since I've dealt with parser generators.

It would appear you need a LR(1) parser which im not sure Happy is. I am positive once I write this someone will be able to correct me.

If your parser can't look ahead it will be stuck on this statement forever

```
Markups1    :: { [Markup] }
        : Markups1 Markup1 
        | Markup1
```

It will look for a Markups1, which in turn looks for a Markups1. Best I can guess, it isnt peforming a look ahead to Markup1 to see if it is a string.

Try rewriting it like this

```
Markups1    :: { [Markup] }
        : Markup1 Markups1
        |
```

Essentially you want it to find the string first, then try to look for another string, if it doesn't find one it needs to end that statement.

Comment: I agree the lists are suspect - I usually write it `: x xs { $1 : $2 } |  { [] }`.

Comment: Oh, and on the topic of LR parsing, [see this manual page](http://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/sec-glr.html)

Comment: "Classic" Happy is LALR(1). @TomMD - I'm not sure the status of the GLR extension - although its in the code base, the last time I tried it I wasn't sure it was working. Also I think the GLR extension was written more for natural language parsing rather than parsing (ambiguous) programming languages.

Comment: Actually, I think my "style" is necessary if you want to do something like `: Expressions ';' Expression | Expression` where it's not mandatory to have a final `;` but you want to be sure that there's at least *one* `Expression`. I'm not sure what parsing style that is, but I just got used to it and don't think I'll change back. :)

Comment: Ah, interesting.  For that purpose I got used to making mutual recursive non-null (NN) rule and a possibly-null rule.  `listNN : elem list { $1 : $2 }` and `list : listNN { $1 } | {}`